# How to flip a single bit in tensor flow tensor without destroying the original tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an array `arr = tf.Variable(initial_value=[True, False, True], dtype=tf.bool)`
Now, I need to flip one bit of arr and assign it to a new variable during the session. I have to do that for each bit in the loop.

I can do the in-place replacement in arr but that destroys the original tensor arr
as below (which is not correct!)

```
import tensorflow as tf

arr = tf.Variable(initial_value=[True, False, True], dtype=tf.bool)
flipped_bit = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
flipped_arr = tf.assign(arr[flipped_bit],
                        tf.math.logical_not(arr[flipped_bit]))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print('Original', sess.run(arr))
for i in range(0, 3):
    print('flipped arr', i, sess.run(flipped_arr, feed_dict={flipped_bit: i}))
```

Now, I have a solution by creating a mask, but can we do this just by using tensorflow only?

The solution I have.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

arr = tf.Variable(initial_value=[True, False, True],
                  trainable=False,
                  dtype=tf.bool)

mask = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=arr.shape)
flipped_arr = tf.math.logical_xor(arr, mask)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print('Original', sess.run(arr))
for flip_bit in range(0, 3):
    mask_val = np.zeros(arr.shape)
    mask_val[flip_bit] = 1
    print('mask', mask_val)
    print(
        'flip_arr', flip_bit,
        sess.run(flipped_arr,
                 feed_dict={
                     flipped_bit: flip_bit,
                     mask: mask_val
                 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in TF2. I believe you can do the same thing in TF1.

```
arr = tf.constant([True, True, False], dtype=tf.bool)
flip = tf.constant([True, False, True], dtype=tf.bool)
flipped_arr = tf.math.logical_xor(arr, flip)

tf.print(arr, flipped_arr) # prints: [1 1 0] [0 1 1]
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that but what about flipping other bits? With this, I need to define a separate flip tensor for each bit flip. This is not scalable to a tensor of large size. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @talos1904 You can create the `flip` array with the same shape as `arr` using `tf.zeros_like` function. But still, you'll have to change the bits you want to flip. What does your problem look like? Maybe I'll be able to help more.